# How to disable WinForms button if SourceList is empty

Tags: dynamic-data, reactiveui

I've been using ReactiveUI with WinForms and just did the switch to DynamicData, using a SourceList instead of a ReactiveBindingList.

As per [this issue](https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData/issues/182), WinForms IBindingList Collection Support was added.

I have a listbox which I bind to a list of strings. In order to make it work with WinForms, I've created a BindingList which is connected to the SourceList:

```
var Images = new SourceList<string>();
var ImagesBindableWinForms = new BindingList<string>();
Images.Connect().Bind(ImagesBindableWinForms).Subscribe();
```

The BindingList is then bound to the listbox as follows, which works swell:

```
d(this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.AdInfo.ImagesBindableWinForms, x => x.listImages.DataSource));
```

There is a button to remove items form the list. It should be disabled if the list is empty. Before switching to SourceList, this used to work:

```
ViewModel.DeleteImageCmd = ReactiveCommand.Create(DeleteImage, ViewModel.CanDeleteImage());

public IObservable<bool> CanDeleteImage()
{
    var canDeleteImage = this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.AdInfo.Images.Count)
        .Select(x => x > 0);
    return canDeleteImage;
}
```

The code would enable or disable the button depending on the list count.

The same code no longer works. I guess no event is fired when the count is updated.

How would I go about disabling the button if the SourceList is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to create an ObservableCollectionExtended and bind that to the SourceList as well. The CanDeleteImage should use that instead of the SourceList, or the BindingList:

```
var ImagesBindable = new ObservableCollectionExtended<string>();
Images.Connect().Bind(ImagesBindable).Subscribe();
public IObservable<bool> CanDeleteImage()
{
    var canDeleteImage = this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.AdInfo.ImagesBindable.Count)
        .Select(x => x > 0);
    return canDeleteImage;
}
```

Only disadvantage is that I now have three lists, but it works.